# Sorting of data in array list C# Windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am trying to sort my data in the array list.

For example the format of the data is as below:

"9:34 AM~Schedule 12" .

And i want it to **sort according to the time only**    "**9:34 AM**~Schedule 12" .

Below is the code to sort it but it doesn't seem to work:

```
Array.Sort(timeSplit, delegate(string first, string second, string third)
{
    return DateTime.Compare(Convert.ToDateTime(first), Convert.ToDateTime(second), third);
});
```

Comment: what is the `third`? the method delegate only takes two parameters, the first and the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should remove the third string because the sort delegate only takes two parameters.
Second the data you pass it is not a valid `DateTime` you should convert it to date time first.
So:

```
Array.Sort(timeSplit, delegate(string first, string second)
{
    //assuming all data have the same format: "9:34 AM~Schedule 12" .
    int firstLength = first.IndexOf("~");
    int secondLength = second.indexOf("~");

    return DateTime.Compare(Convert.ToDateTime(first.Substring(0, firstLength)), Convert.ToDateTime(second.Substring(0, secondLength)));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is almost certainly where you are trying to convert your string into a DateTime:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(first)
```

Your string is not in a 'standard' format.

I would suggest using SubString to remove the "~Schedule", text, then parsing with a fomat string:

```
var myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("9:34 AM~Schedule 12".Substring(0,7), "h:mm tt");
```

You can then use DateTime.TimeOfDay in your comparison.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like:

```
        string[] arr = new string[]
        {
            "9:34 AM~Schedule 1",
            "11:34 PM~Schedule 12",
            "9:34 AM~Schedule 3",
            "10:14 AM~Schedule 10",
            "9:34 AM~Schedule 2",
            "9:30 PM~Schedule 12"
        };

        var ordered = from a in arr
                      let split = a.Split('~')
                      orderby Convert.ToDateTime(split[0]), split[1]
                      select a;

        string[] orderedData = ordered.ToArray();
```